# Standard way to create a hash in Java

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha256

The question is about the correct way of creating a hash in Java:
Lets assume I have a positive `BigInteger` value that I would like to create a hash from. Lets assume that below instance of the `messageDigest`  is a valid instance of `(SHA-256)`

```
public static final BigInteger B = new BigInteger("BD0C61512C692C0CB6D041FA01BB152D4916A1E77AF46AE105393011BAF38964DC46A0670DD125B95A981652236F99D9B681CBF87837EC996C6DA04453728610D0C6DDB58B318885D7D82C7F8DEB75CE7BD4FBAA37089E6F9C6059F388838E7A00030B331EB76840910440B1B27AAEAEEB4012B7D7665238A8E3FB004B117B58", 16);

   byte[] byteArrayBBigInt = B.toByteArray();
   this.printArray(byteArrayBBigInt);
   messageDigest.reset();
   messageDigest.update(byteArrayBBigInt);
   byte[] outputBBigInt = messageDigest.digest();
```

Now I only assume that the code below is correct,  as according to the test the hashes I produce match with the one produced by:

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=BD0C61512C692C0CB6D041FA01BB152D4916A1E77AF46AE105393011BAF38964DC46A0670DD125B95A981652236F99D9B681CBF87837EC996C6DA04453728610D0C6DDB58B318885D7D82C7F8DEB75CE7BD4FBAA37089E6F9C6059F388838E7A00030B331EB76840910440B1B27AAEAEEB4012B7D7665238A8E3FB004B117B58

However I am not sure why we are doing the step below i.e.
because the returned byte array after the digest() call is signed and in this case it is a negative, I suspect that we do need to convert it to a positive number i.e. we can use a function like that.

```
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
      result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

thus:

```
String hex = byteArrayToHexString(outputBBigInt)
BigInteger unsignedBigInteger = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```

When I construct a `BigInteger` from the new hex string and convert it back to byte array then I see that the sign bit, that is most significant bit i.e. the leftmost bit, is set to 0 which means that the number is positive, moreover the whole byte is constructed from zeros ( 00000000 ).

My question is: Is there any RFC that describes why do we need to convert the hash always to a "positive" unsigned byte array. I mean even if the number produced after the digest call is negative it is still a valid hash, right? thus why do we need that additional procedure. Basically, I am looking for a paper: standard or rfc describing that we need to do so.

Comment: My 2 cents:

1. It's positive probably due to the fact it's easier to locate the hash bucket for such a hashCode by simply do hashCode % bucketSize; But I am not expert on this.

2. Your code is bad in style in the senes that the time complexity of hashCode() grows with the length of the input string and is O(n) implementation. Believe me we used to have serious problem on such implementation. You probably want to change it to some characteristic fixed sized array of part of the whole string.

Comment: how would you sujjest to change it . The big Integer is not a fixed length the the byte array length is also not fixed. The one thing i could imagine is validating that the BigInteger length is not greater then some Max length.  But other that this do you have a example of what you proposed?

Comment: Your question isn't really about hashing, but if about converting big integers to byte arrays.

Comment: well i would not say it like that, as the method toByteArray() converts the big integer to byte array however in order to get the same result i.e. the same the hash as shown in fileformat.info, then i need to apply some additional logic to that byte array.  You can call it about hashing or converting big integers to byte array , at the end the question is very precise i.e. why do we need that one additional last step i.e. the method byteArrayToHexString in my case and is there a standart /RFI where i can read more about it.

Comment: @Tito Usually you'd take the most representative section of the entire string (up to your business scenario). For example if you know the first 24 chars are the key, why not just take it; or, you give an upper threshold for the byte length, say, 128 and truncate anything after that.

Comment: @AlexSuo the example you provided is a good and is working if the value you take hash is the final one but if you will have to do additional computations based on the hash, i mean some cryptographic computations that are part of a formula this is no go.

Answer (score 1):

A hash consists of an octet string (called a byte array in Java). How you convert it to or from a large number (a `BigInteger` in Java) is completely out of the scope for cryptographic hash algorithms. So no, there is no RFC to describe it as there is (usually) no reason to treat a hash as a number. In that sense a cryptographic hash is rather different from `Object.hashCode()`.

That you can only treat hexadecimals as unsigned is a bit of an issue, but if you really want to then you can first convert it back to a byte array, and then perform `new BigInteger(result)`. That constructor does threat the encoding within result as signed. Note that in protocols it is often not needed to convert back and forth to hexadecimals; hexadecimals are mainly for human consumption, a computer is fine with bytes.

Comment: ECDSA is one of those algorithms where the hash is actually directly used as a number, but how this number behaves is particular to the algorithm, not the other way around (although most cryptographers prefer unsigned big endian notation).